# Xode error: Bundle identifiers must be unique, but I already reset my iPhone as a new iPhone Device

Tags: ios, xcode

Xcode error

Details

Unable to install "live4iphoneDev"
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402653008

```
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2022-08-25 03:04:04 +0000";
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
}
```

This application or a bundle it contains has the same bundle identifier as this application or another bundle that it contains. Bundle identifiers must be unique.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402653008

MacOS 12.5.1 (21G83), Xode Version 13.4 (13F17a)

Just error for this app, I use a wildcard code sign certificate.

Already try reboot my iPhone and Mac, it doesn't work.

I also try change to another sign certificate, it also now work.

Comment: What is the bundle ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This finally solved by reinstalling Xcode Version 13.4.1 (13F100)